# Removing specific patterns from rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure it out how to count rows which start with a number, for example:

```
My_col

24 was 2020 - There is a lot -
23 aka 2018 -  how many ...
23 was 2020 - wonderful!
no numbers this time
```

and, only if starts with a number, remove the words before the three words before `-`:

```
My_col

There is a lot -
how many ...
wonderful!
no numbers this time
```

Using SQL I would do it the check as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(My_Col), 1, 1)) = 1 
         THEN 'yes' 
         ELSE 'no' 
       END AS StartsWithNumber
FROM my_data
```

I think for removing words before `-` I should consider the use of `np.where` or `regex` then `apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'My_col': [
          "24 was 2020 - There is a lot -", 
          "no numbers this time"] })

df['My_col'].apply(
    lambda x: x[x.find("-")+1:].strip() if x[0].isdigit() else x)
```

Output:

```
0        There is a lot -
1    no numbers this time
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `df.replace()` and regex. I added a `-` in the 4th line to show doesn't remove words:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'My_col':['24 was 2020 - There is a lot -', '23 aka 2018 -  how many ...', '23 was 2020 - wonderful!', 'no numbers this - time']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['My_col'].replace(r'^\d.*?-','', regex=True, inplace = True)
print(df)

                   My_col
0        There is a lot -
1            how many ...
2              wonderful!
3  no numbers this - time
```

Comment: @mujjiga's answer is about 30% faster than my answer if that matters. The regex answer I gave is a bit more flexible for other use cases though so I'll leave it up in case it helps others